# Python script to store Json files in real time to amazon S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a python code that gives me tweets in real time using Twitter Streaming API. I have stored the output to a json file which keeps on updating dynamically as new tweets arrive.However, I would like to save this json to amazon **s3** which I could use to trigger events using amazon lambda service.Can somebody suggest me a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amazon has a python library to interact with it's web services. It's called [`Boto`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and supports both S3 and lambda services.

To save the json to S3:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.create_bucket(Bucket='jsonbucket')
s3.Object('jsonbucket', 'yourstoredjson.json').put(Body=open('yourlocaljson.json', 'rb'))
```

Note: before saving files to S3 with boto, you have to [set up authentication credentials](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html#configuration) for AWS.

Comment: Does this script save locally as well, don't you have to use IO library ? @sc3w

Comment: This uploads a local file to S3.

Comment: Ah thank you for clarification,  here is the post of my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59165498/use-python-io-to-upload-requests-to-s3-bucket-without-saving-file-locally