# Trying to write a new Json file to s3

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am trying to write a JSON file to s3. My question is this. I have a bucket. I have the name of the filename. However, I have a file structure that I want to write it to. This is my current code.

```
s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=path.replace(' ', '_'), Body=contents)
```

The folder structure WITHIN the buck is something like /json/latest.

I looked through this link and I still don't understand where I would specify this. Thanks!

[Python script to store Json files in real time to amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36998498/python-script-to-store-json-files-in-real-time-to-amazon-s3)

Is there not a path in the put object where I can specify the folder structure. I have looked into the API and don't see anything that does this. Thanks!

Comment: The key contains the path and the name, e.g. `json/latest/some_file.json`

Comment: Thank you. I was making it more complicated than it needed to be. It appears.